# Inheriting repostories in multimodule project

Tags: testing, gradle

I want to imitate dependency resolving in my tests. I expect that repositories will be inheriting by sub projects from sup projects. To check it

```
Project sup = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
sup.repositories {mavenCentral()}
Project sub = ProjectBuilder.builder().withParent(sup).build()
sup.repositories {mavenCentral()} //just to be sure

sub.apply plugin:  'java'
sub.dependencies {compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0'}

sub.configurations.findByName('compile').resolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure()
```

But it fails

```
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':test:compile'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find group:com.google.guava, module:guava, version:14.0.
Required by:
test:test:unspecified
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$StaticVersionResolveResult.notFound(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:159)
...
```

I can fixit by adding `sub.repositories {mavenCentral()}`  . But for me it seems like it should work without it.

I still use gradle 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle uses *configuration injection* instead of inheritance, which is equally concise but cleaner and more flexible. In your case, you could do something like `sup.allprojects { repositories { mavenCentral() } }`.

To learn more about configuration injection, see [Injected configuration](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3ainjected_configuration) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).